# Backbone click event not firing in template View

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I am working on a Backbone application which is based on a dynamic template . I have a header view, a side panel view and footer view that are dynamically initialized when calling any other view .
The problem is I have events on each template view that are not firing. For example i have a button that changes the language in the header view but its event isn't firing.

My header View  :

```
define([ "jquery", "backbone", "text!../../pages/header.html" ], function($,
        Backbone, headerTpl) {

    var header = Backbone.View.extend({
        events : {
            "click #enBtn":"swichToEnglish",
             "click #frBtn":"swichToFrench"
        },
        initialize : function(options) {
             _.bindAll(this, "swichToFrench","swichToEnglish");

            this.render(options.parent);
            //$("#enBtn").css("pointer-events","none");

        },
        render : function(parent) {
            this.template = _.template(headerTpl);
            $(parent).append(this.template);
            return this;
        },
        swichToFrench:function(){
            console.log("switch to frensh");
            if(i18n.currentLocal == 'en'){
                i18n.currentLocal='fr';
                $("#frBtn").css("pointer-events","auto");
                this.render(options.parent);
        }
        },
        swichToEnglish:function(){
            console.log("switch to English");
            if(i18n.currentLocal == 'fr'){
                i18n.currentLocal='en';
                $("#enBtn").css("pointer-events","auto");
                $("#frBtn").css("pointer-events","none");
                this.render(options.parent);
        }   
        }
    });

    return header;
});
```

The header view is called in the router :

```
self._header = new Header({parent: $(".main_container")});
```

Any ideas how to fix this issue. I need to know haw to fire these events Thank You.

Comment: (1) `this.template` will be a function, not a piece of HTML. (2) What does the template look like?

Comment: This.template is a html load using the text library you can see it in the require declaration

Comment: (1) `this.template = _.template(headerTpl);` means that `this.template` will be a function, not a string. (2) But what does the template actually look like? (3) You're also sometimes calling `render` with the `parent` argument and sometimes without it, you're also calling `$('#enBtn')` when you really should be using `this.$('#enBtn')`.

Comment: What i mean when I said template is different views each has its own html  and these views are loaded each time i call any other view . Regarding the render function you are right I fixed it and I call to display the proper language as you can see I am using i18

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your event handlers is not firing is because the event handlers are delegated to the views element, but you're appending the template to some other element. Since the target elements are in this template which is not appended the view's `el`, the events will never bubble into the handlers delegated to it.

---

Apart from that, as @mu is too short pointed out, when you do `$(parent).append(this.template);`,
`this.template` is the template function. You should actually call it with the data to get the template.
and you shouldn't be using global selectors like `$('')` and use `this.$el.find('')` instead as best practice.

also, `options` is only available inside the `initialize` method, and is `undefined` outside.

Instead of passing the parent into the view and then have it append itself to parent, do that outside the view and make the view independent.

Also declare the [`template`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-template) property in the view rather than adding it after the creation as a best practice.

And there's no need to bind the context of event handlers to the view manually,  by default the context of event handler will be the view.

Your view should look like:

```
define([ "jquery", "backbone", "text!../../pages/header.html" ], function($,
    Backbone, headerTpl) {

  var header = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function(options) {
        this.render();
    },
    template: _.template(headerTpl),
    events : {
        "click #enBtn":"swichToEnglish",
        "click #frBtn":"swichToFrench"
    },
    render : function() {
        this.$el.append(this.template(/* pass the data here*/));
     //--------^----- this is required for the events to work
        return this;
    },
    swichToFrench:function(){
        if(i18n.currentLocal == 'en'){
            i18n.currentLocal='fr';
            this.$el.find("#frBtn").css("pointer-events","auto");
            this.render();
        }
    },
    swichToEnglish:function(){
        if(i18n.currentLocal == 'fr'){
          i18n.currentLocal='en';
          this.$el.find("#enBtn").css("pointer-events","auto");
          this.$el.find("#frBtn").css("pointer-events","none");
          this.render();
      }   
    }
  });

  return header;
});
```

Which you can create like:

```
self._header = new Header();
$(".main_container").append(self._header.el);
```

---

it looks like you just want the view content to be added to `'.main_container'`, and doesn't need another element. In that case you can make your views `el` point to it rather than creating a new element by passing it as `el` in the options like:

```
self._header = new Header({
 el: '.main_container' // this.el will refer to `.main_container` in view
});
```

then you don't have to do `$(".main_container").append(self._header.el);`

---

if you must pass the parent into view as an options for some reason, then you should cache it in the view inside `initialize` so that you can refer it elsewhere like.

```
this.parent = options.parent
```

---

*side note:*

As you can see, I've changed the order in which you had declared the view's properties - `initialize` on top followed by template, event and render.

We initialize the view, we create the templating function, we declare the events to be delegated, and then we render the view.

The order in which you define properties doesn't matter internally, but when another developer looks at your code, it's much easier to digest. But it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: Thank You it works but it add the header to the bottom of the page it doesn't replace the existing header (I have two headers one in top and one at the end of the page because we are using append and when I use .html it displays only the header and the rest disappears) is There a way to render the entire page when I choose another language . Thnx :)

Comment: @ELKamel I didn't get what exactly the problem is.. but if you want the header at the top rather than bottom, use `prepend()` instead of `append()`..?

Comment: No that is not the problem, the problem is the header will be duplicated not replaced probably .empt() is not working